# Beamer themes cannot be found / Ubuntu / I've tried every folder one can imagine

Tags: beamer, ubuntu, themes, folders

I would like to use the theme for `beamer` called `amsterdam` (`\usetheme{amsterdam})`. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Tex Live 2014. 
I've tried to place that `beamerthemeAmsterdam.sty` to everywhere, but it gives me error that it cannot be found.

I've tried these:

> /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/
>
> /home/username/texmf/ <--- I created that texmf folder there.
>
> /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/
>
> /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/

What is the problem? Default themes are in here:

> /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/

but I cannot use even those; I get the same error!

I'm using Sublime Text as an editor (with latextools). Everything else is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Amsterdam theme is not among the default ones. You have to download and install it by your own and then run texhash to let your distribution know you have installed something new.

Comment: [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Comment: Yes I ran texhash. Doesn't help. And I do know that amsterdam is not default theme, but that cannot be the problem cause even the default themes cannot be found. Any solutions?

Comment: maybe you need to type `\usetheme{Amsterdam}` (with a capital A)?

Comment: Perhaps you have another tex system. Run some small hello-world document and check in the log-file the pathes of standard files like artice.cls.

Comment: I think that @dcmst already had the right answer (in the comment above). Mixing up capital and lower-case letters in commands that get translated to file names is problematic.

Answer (score 8):

run in a terminal:

```
kpsewhich beamerthemedefault.sty
```

and you'll get the exact position of that file. However, that is the official directory, where personal files schould *not* go. There is an local texmf tree. You can get that directory by running

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
```

On my system I'll get

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

In that directory create a subdirectory like

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/beamer/
```

and put your personal file in there. Then run `texhash` from the command line to update the data base. A following

```
kpsewhich beamerthemeAmsterdam.sty
```

should give the complete path.